# Exchange Data between Page and NavMenu in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I have a standard - blazor - project which has the following components:

```
-> MainLayout.razor
-> NavMenu.razor
-> Pages/Index.razor
-> Pages/Sub1.razor
```

The MainLayout looks like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
<div>@Body</div>
```

Now I want to exchange Data between my pages (index.razor, sub1.razor) and the navmenu so I could add something like this in navmenu:

```
<div><p>You are now on Page: @CurrentPageName</p></div>
```

How can I set (navMenu).CurrentPageName directly from within my page? I would expect that using a static class for that is not really a good option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A better scoped-service implementation:

```
 public class CurrentPage
    {
        public string CurrentPageName { get; private set; }

        public void SetCurrentPageName(string name)
        {
            if (!string.Equals(CurrentPageName, name)) 
            {
                CurrentPageName = name;
                NotifyStateChanged();
            }
        }

        public event Action OnChange; // event raised when changed

        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
    }
```

We are not passing round dictionaries of objects, we have a simple service that does one thing. The only way to change the page is call `SetCurrentPageName`, which raises an event to let consumers know the name changed. This is required between un-nested components as updates would not otherwise propagate across.

We also need to register the service (as scoped since the current page is session-specific) in startup:

```
            services.AddScoped<CurrentPage>();
```

We will inject in `Index.razor`, and use it:

```
@page "/"
@inject CurrentPage currentPage

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<button @onclick="ChangeName">Set Page Name</button>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
@code
{

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        currentPage.SetCurrentPageName("The Home Page");
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    void ChangeName() => currentPage.SetCurrentPageName("Name changed");
}
```

and finally at the top of `NavMenu.razor`:

```
@inject CurrentPage currentPage
```

and further down..

```
    <p>The current page is @currentPage.CurrentPageName</p>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // if the OnChange event is raised, refresh this view
        currentPage.OnChange += () => StateHasChanged();

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
```

This state class doesn't know anything about how it's used and there are no objects or references being passed about.

[EDIT] I decided that the inject/override pattern for setting the page name is rather unBlazor, so I also wrote a component to simplify this - PageName.razor:

```
@inject CurrentPage currentPage;

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        currentPage.SetCurrentPageName(Name);
    }
}
```

Now any page wanting to set the title can do this:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject HttpClient Http
<PageName Name="Weather forecast page!" />
```

The whole consumer is now a component :)

Comment: Shouldn't the first solution implement IDisposal and release the OnChange registration on disposal?

Answer (score 3):

There are three main ways to communicate between components in Blazor. Chris Sainty has a good article outlining these: https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/

In this scenario a cascading value or a state container are probably the best options. 
A cascading value would require a top-level component to contain the value, e.g. something that encapsulates both the `<NavMenu>` and the `@Body`:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<MenuState>
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="http://blazor.net" target="_blank" class="ml-md-auto">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
</MenuState>
```

Another approach is to use an injectable service that provides a State service, which you inject into both the `<NavMenu>` and the page components.

Comment: How can you use cascading value from "a top-level component" to 'low-level' (children)  components  ? The flow of data is not downstream, but upstream. He wants to issue a message, say, in FetchData page, and see it  in the LayoutComponent ( navmenu )

Comment: i was able to use the "state container" - way described in the url

Comment: @enet Components can pass parameters down to child components via Cascading values. There is nothing that says the value has to be a value object, it can be a class that provides the necessary functionality, like a state container. This is an alternative to using DI. Both methods are valid

Comment: @ Quango, what you say is true, but has no bearing on the issue I raise in my comment: He wants to issue a message, say, in FetchData page, and see it in the LayoutComponent ( navmenu )...How do you do that.

Comment: @Ole Albers, Please post your working solution, so we can all profit from your good question.

Answer (score -2):

Use scoped service to share data / objects

In Startup.cs

you can add your own 'Scoped' service :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ......
   services.AddScoped<MyScopeService>();
}
```

```
public class MyScopeService : Dictionary<string,object>
{
}
```

and in NavMenu.razor

```
@inject MyScopeService mss

@code{
    string _title;
    public void UpdateTitle(string title)
    {
        _title = title;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

@{
    mss["NavMenu"] = this;
}
<div>@_title</div>
```

In target page :

```
@inject MyScopeService mss
@code{
    void SetTitle()
    {
        NavMenu menu = (NavMenu)mss["NavMenu"];
        menu.UpdateTitle("Hello this is page 1");
    }
}

<button @onclick="SetTitle">SetTitle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting an answer but it's not really very good code. I was going to explain all the bad points but there are only 500 chars in a comment and it would take a lot more to cover all the issues here. I'll post a solution using the the same concept of a scoped service to help you.